# Dropdown menu on Navbar not working on bootstrap 5 using ng add installation method

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5

**My setup:**

I'm using Angular 11.2.11, Bootstrap 5, running on Windows. The project I'm running is using SCSS.

**Problem:**

I'm using the codes available on bootstrap documentation ([found here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)) to add a Navbar to my website:

[image: Navbar on my website]

So, on my terminal, in my folder project, I run the following command:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

But, the dropdown menu is not working, I click it and nothing happens.

The bootstrap installation method I used is the one [found here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

**What I tried:**

All the solutions I found were from other type of installation (i.e. manual install on older versions of Angular and Bootstrap).

The Bootstrap tutorial ([found here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)), says I don't need to manual add Jquery and Popper (the solutions I found for previous versions of Angular and Bootstrap said that I needed to manually add it, but it didn't work too, and is not recommended in the offical instalation guide for the newer versions).

I tried inserting on `angular.json` file the bootstrap location, but also don't work, like this:

```
            "styles": [
              "../Istim/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Also tried the following command: `npm install jquery popper.js --save`

Comment: ng-bootstrap is a library that use bootstrap.css, but not jQuery nor popper.js. But you need check the docs about ng-bootstrap to create the drop-downs -it's different html that the html used by bootstrap:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

Comment: Thank you for you comment, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: the ngBootstrap example codes are not working for me too, do I inserted the html of the examples on my code and the dropdown menu itens are shown outside of it. I just copy pasted the html presented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

complementary my comment, after import NgbDropDownModule in your module

```
import {NgbDropdownModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [..., NgbDropdownModule],
    ...
})
```

And add the bootstrap.css (the best option is make it is include in the angular.json file)

You can write (see where are the `ngbDropdown`, the `ngbDropdropToggle` and the `ngbDropdownMenu`)

Is only add the before "directives" in the example of bootstrap nav-bar

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" ngbDropdownToggle 
                 id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

To make the "collapsive menu" we can use the own NgbCollapseModule like is showed in the [docs of ngb-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)

Really it's only declare a variable `isMenuCollapsed:boolean=false` and in the button

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="isMenuCollapsed = !isMenuCollapsed" 
         aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Of course we add the directive `[ngbCollapse]` to the menu

```
<div [ngbCollapse]="isMenuCollapsed" 
     class="collapse navbar-collapse position-relative" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Really I like that the "collapsible" menu was inside a div position absolute to "float" over the page the menu. Well is a bit complex and I'm not very good in .css, but in this [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c6q3wv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-bar.component.html) (I added also the "search" as Output using a FormControl) I left a nav-bar like "bootstrap"

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Whats the best way to use bootstrap on Angular. This way (ngBootstrap) or the manual install?

Comment: I love ng-bootstrap (avoid jQuery -remember that Angular and jQuery are not very friendly- and you has all the functionality of bootstrap.js), so it's possible that I am not objective. But remember that they are two different ways to do "the same". My choose are going to be ng-bootstrap because is "angular"